# What happens with records from Kafka that wait for processing in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am tuning my spark-streaming + kafka stream program. And sometimes I met with exceptions like cannot find spark files in HDFS or cannot compute splits in spark executors. According to some blogs or answers in the internet, these might be a not-enough-memory problem due to data piling up in receivers. But I've set the SparkStreaming StorageLevel to `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER`. I thought that the receiver should persist the latest coming batches to disk storage instead of discarding the oldest batch rdd when there's not enough memory.

What happens to the receiver memory if there are data piling up? Or why `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER` did not work?